# save last value and use it to calc diff (shiny app)

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on the implementation of a Shiny app that is updated every day.
Currently I am encountering difficulties on a step requiring to evaluate the evolution of a value on the same variable (value).
So I need to retain the previous value, to make it appear in a column created (old_value) and to calculate the difference (diff) between the new and old value.

I have read several articles/issues from other users but I haven't been able to solve my case...
A minimal app is presented

an other exemple to explain what I am looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fyO2.png

Thank you very much for your help.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


mydata <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     IDproduct = c("112A", "207V", "202D"),
                     #Emonth = c("04/02/2020", "24/07/2020", "19/08/2020"),
                     #Smonth = c("Apr2018", "May2017", "Jan2016"),
                     value= c(2100,2338, 3225 ),
                     old_value= c(2100,2450,3500),
                     diff=c("diff between 'old' and 'new' value", "diff between 'old' and 'new' value", "diff between 'old' and 'new' value"))



ui <- shinyServer(
  fluidRow( dataTableOutput("newValue")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  # Function to get new observations
  get_new_data <- function(){
    data <- mydata  %>% data.frame
    return(data)}
  
  # Initialize my_data
  my_data <<- get_new_data()
  
  # Function to update my_data
  update_data <- function(){
    my_data <<- rbind(get_new_data(), my_data)}
  
  
  # DataTable
            output$newValue = renderDT(my_data)
})


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
### gather old data from previous day

locacion <- 'C:\\My Disk Space\\_My Work\\RStuff\\GWS'

myolddata <- read.csv(paste0(locacion,"\\myolddata",Sys.Date()-1,".csv"), header=TRUE)

###  this is the new data
mydata <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     IDproduct = c("112A", "207V", "202D"),
                     value = c(2100,2338, 3225 ))

ui <- shinyServer(
  fluidRow( DTOutput("newValue")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  # Function to get new observations
  get_new_data <- function(){
    data <- mydata %>% select(IDproduct,value)
    return(data)}

  # Initialize my_data2 - old value
  mydata2 <- reactive({
    olddata <- myolddata %>% select(IDproduct,old_value=value)  
    olddata
  })

  # Function to update my_data
  my_data <- reactive({
    data <- merge(get_new_data(), mydata2(), by = "IDproduct") %>% mutate(diff = value - old_value)
    return(data)
  })
  
  ###   save the new data as myolddata for next day's run
  ###   need to save as .csv or another feasible format
  write.csv(get_new_data(), paste0(locacion,"\\myolddata",Sys.Date(),".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  
  # DataTable
  output$newValue = renderDT(my_data())
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: thank you for your response.
the idea is there but I think I don't understand everything (beginner).

in your suggestion it seems "simple" in the sense that we have 2 distinct bases (mydata1, mydata2) (mydata2 update mydata1). 

In my case it's the same base that updates automatically... 

currently I don't have access to this database to test in real. 

would you have a solution to test your example on dynamic data as close as possible to my situation please?

Comment: In my exemple, I tried as I could to present an evolution of the base (left side) and on the right side a reactive table of the evolution. Indeed the base1 overwrites the previous version every day.
Would shiny or an sql procedure could "capture" the value and assign the date of the update in order to perform the job required?

Comment: Please see the updated code.  You need to save a copy of the old data as myolddata_2020-10-26.csv and run the program.  Everyday you run the code you get a new copy of the data as myolddata_todaysdate.csv

Comment: Thank you! 
I haven't tested it yet but I understand the process.
I am very grateful for the time and patience you have shown with me.